# Inkscape cannot convert SVG to EPS

Tags: svg, inkscape, eps

This is really driving me nuts. I attempted almost everything but without success. I cannot convert successfully a `SVG` file to `EPS` (see/download figure [here (Figure_2.svg)](https://github.com/mdepitta/tmp)). I tried to ungroup and raise everything to top layer as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245685/inkscape-screws-up-eps-files), as well as to change the background from transparent to white. But still panels E and F do not appear. The only workaround is to export the figure in `PNG` with high resolution. But considering that the figure is for a publication, it is not the ideal solution. Any idea? Working on Inkscape 0.91 (r13725) on Fedora 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels D and E consist of bitmap images masked by rectangles.

This doesn't seem to export well to EPS, but here is a workaround:

- Select the 4 panels (or repeat this procedure 4 times).
- *Object -> Mask -> Release*; this will undo the mask into a rectangle and an image (object and mask) for each of the 4 attractor renderings.
- Somehow the 4 images appear white over black background. You can invert the images using color filters: selecting the 4 images, then *Filters -> Color -> Invert*; select *Invert lightness*.

Now the figure should look OK and exports well to EPS.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. If you could edit when you have the chance your response to briefly explain me the reasons of the two operations and what they actually do I would appreciate it. Meanwhile I approve your reply. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, an update on this. Although it does not solve the issue. Imagemagick succeeds (which makes me think that it is a Inkscape bug still):

```
convert Figure_2.svg Figure_2.eps
```

works just fine. To install Imagemagick for linux, follow the guidelines [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php).

Comment: Note that ImageMagick operates on bitmap images only. The SVG is rasterized into a bitmap, then saved as EPS.